# Eclipse Android SDK ERROR: unknown virtual device name

Tags: android, linux, eclipse, android-emulator, cocos2d-iphone

So, the issue i correctly installed eclipse,android sdk,ndk, coocs2d-x 2.1.4. I can build cocos2d-x android project, import it to eclipse, etc. Everything seems fine, but not really. The problem is that i can't launch my virtual machine to emulate andoid OS. I created avd, it works fine with simple android projects, but when i use it to run cocos2d-x project as android application it does nothing. No output at all. I found [this guide](http://nigam.biz/cocos2dx/md___users_nigamshah__library__developer_cocos2d-x-2_81_84_tools_android-emulator-_r_e_a_d_m_e.html) and followed it. But i faced a problem. 1st of all, when i follow this step:

> Now start the Android for x86 Intel Emulator using  the following command:

```
$ <SDK directory>/tools/emulator-x86 -avd Your_AVD_Name -qemu -m 2047 -enable-kvm
```

i have an error message:

> gloomist-CN tools # ./emulator-x86 @myavd -qemu -m 2047 -enable-kvm 
>   emulator: ERROR: unknown virtual device name: 'myavd'
>   emulator: could not find virtual device named 'myavd'

But it is in sdk as a valid android virtual device. And the next one. In that tutorial that i pasted link to above, the last step is:

```
Run the emulator with the correct library path and options

Make sure to

    Set the library path to the directory containing the Open GL library for the emulator (LD_LIBRARY_PATH=...)
    Run the x86 version of the emulator (run /tools/emulator-x86)
    Enable GPU use (Use the option "-gpu on")
    Also, you need to specify the name of the Android Virtual Device to use (Use the option "-avd ")

On OS X the command line looks like this

    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/bin/android-sdk/tools/lib ~/bin/android-sdk/tools/emulator-x86 -verbose -avd android17x86 -gpu on
```

i don't really know what author meant by all this. Could anyone explain me the way to do it in linux?

So basically, the main problem is: how to run a cocos2d-x project on AVD in eclipse on lixnux? That's it.

I use Linux version 3.2.0-23-generic (buildd@palmer) (gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu4) ) #36-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 10 20:41:14 UTC 2012 (Ubuntu 3.2.0-23.36-generic 3.2.14).

Can anyone help me to figure out how can i accurately launch my cocos2d-x project on AVD using eclipse?

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure 'myavd' is a valid avd?

Try to run this command to get a list of AVD's you have created in your system:

```
# <SDK directory>/tools/android list avd
```

And re-run **emulator-x86** passing a valid avd.

I also suggest you follow the step by step guide about how to configure your android enviroment which comes with cocos2d-x dist. You can find it in: **/samples/Cpp/TestCpp/proj.android/README.md**

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

I was able to fix this error on Ubuntu 18.04 by running:

```
sudo chmod 777 /dev/kvm
```

Its not exactly high security, but it gets the job done.